# How can the Dhamma help internet admins be fair?

Tags: discussion

Admins behave inappropriately at times. This leads to suffering for the admins and everyone. They make mistakes because they are human. It's hard to turn anger into compassion and admins can make a lot of people angry. So that's why I'm asking the above question.

Comment: As for the OP question: Dhamma can not possible help a currupted heart, such is not possible.

>The Lord Buddha taught that his Dhamma, when placed in the heart of an ordinary run-of-the-mill person, is bound to be thoroughly corrupted, but if placed in the heart of a Noble One, it is bound to be genuinely pure & authentic, something that at the same time can be neither effaced nor obscured.

Comment: >So as long as we are devoting ourselves merely to the theoretical study of the Dhamma, it can't serve us well. Only when we have trained our hearts to eliminate their 'chameleons' — their defilements — will it benefit us in full measure. And only then will the true Dhamma be kept pure, free from distortions & deviations from its original principles.

>— Phra Ajān Mun Bhūridatto

Comment: For those more interested what has to be developed before one can practice metta, look here: [Karaṇīya Metta-Sutta](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/nanadassana/metta_en.html)

How ever, for you Uuu, and all others still capable to hate: [Aghata Sutta: Hatred](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an10/an10.080.than_en.html)

Answer (score -1):

> How can the Dhamma help internet admins be fair?

It is fair to users and other readers of Buddhism SE to allow an [*off-topic / primarily opinion-based*](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/20603/buddhist-question-for-donald-trump) question with a score of -4 to remain on the front page?

I don't think that's fair to anyone. I don't think that's inappropriate.
 Actually I think it would have been inappropriate to let the question stay open.

We have chat rooms for such questions. Please use them:)

> They make mistakes because they are human.

As mentioned before I don't think this was a mistake. It would have been a mistake to let the question stay open. I guess we have different opinions on that matter. I'll leave it at that.

> It's hard to turn anger into compassion and admins can make a lot of people angry.

Loving-kindness meditation is a great practice for over-coming anger.

Comment: >Lanka: Loving-kindness meditation is a great practice for over-coming anger.

Metta-bhavan without being first upright and secound serious in keeping precepts is more than just hypocratic. Killing, stealing, harming and then do ones "metta", is like the reaction of a snake facing the shadow of the eagle.